Identifying purpose of an Ethereum contract method (0xca350aa6) and why transfert USDC like that?
I've been analyzing an Ethereum transaction and came across a specific method signature: 0xca350aa6. This method is called multiple times in a sequence of transactions from an address to a Coinbase exchange.
I'm trying to understand the exact purpose of this method. Why they do that ? And how can they transfert to much why transfert millions in 5 days ?
The Wallet address is 0x11aC8B22C9295c62D074b025092967f987E50F38
WHY ??
